# Sharing an internet connection through the Ethernet port

Tags: 10.10, networking, configuration, network-manager, routing

I have a small living room PC (Bohica, running fully-updated Ubuntu 10.10/Maverick) connected to my HDTV that I use for web browsing and media streaming.  It connects via WiFi (wlan0) to my Fedora server (Snafu) that in turn connects to the internet.  I use static addressing, and everything has been working fine.

I just got a Blu-ray player, and I'd like to give it wired network access to the internet via Bohica's available wired ethernet port (eth0).  So far, I haven't been to get eth0 and the network configured to get the Blu-ray player talking to the internet.

Here's my wlan0 configuration:

```
 ip4 addr: 192.168.0.100
 mask:     /24 (255.255.255.0)
 gateway:  192.168.0.4 (fedora box)
```

The Blu-ray player is set to an IP of 192.168.0.98/24, with the same gateway as above.

I want eth0 set to an IP of 192.168.0.99/24, but when I do this using nm-connection-editor I lose internet access (the system tries to use eth0 as the default internet access interface).

How do I get my blu-ray player to talk to the internet through Bohica, and do so without disrupting my current (working) network?

Thanks.

Edit: Here's the relevant output from nm-tool with the Blu-ray player connected:

```
$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected

- Device: eth0
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            forcedeth
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        90:FB:A6:2C:94:32

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

- Device: wlan0  [wlan0] 
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ndiswrapper
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:26:5A:C0:D0:05

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.100
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.4
```

Comment: Do I need NAT/MASQ on eth0?  I thought not, since it is already active for wlan0.

Comment: I just followed the recipe here, but no change: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=713874

Comment: Erased the above and tried firestarter, same result.  Specifically, when eth0 is enabled, pinging Snafu (912.168.0.4, my gateway, via wlan0) yields "Destination Host Unreachable".  Disable eth0, and the ping works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was [firestarter](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firestarter).  It quickly and easily did exactly what I needed, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up routing or bridging on your living room PC (but you already know this, because you have a working Fedora Server acting as a router).

I think that you will need to bypass the gui and easy networking tools to get the network config that you want. I haven't seen the "Share this interface" (you know, like on Windows) setting in the gui or easy networking tools on my Ubuntu systems. I haven't looked real hard, so I may have missed the setting.

First, plug the blu-ray device directly into your Fedora Server. Make sure it works in the simple case. This may involve borrowing a long network cable or a second TV, but you really need to reduce the number of variables.

Next, decide on Bridging vs. Routing. Bridging would make the network configuration a bit easier, but in my experience, routing is easier to enable on the gateway host. Routing is usually a kernel option, and you would need to plan out a multi-subnet network. Bridging usually involves installing a package and then configuring it.

Now, look up how to configure your choice (Bridging vs. Routing) on Ubuntu 10.10. I suspect this is where you will need to leave networkmanager behind. It seems clear that network manager is disabling your wlan0 when it has a "better" eth0 connection. I'm not sure how to make network manager stop that, but I suspect the steps for enabling routing and bridging will have you disable network manager.

Finally, test your config. If the blu-ray player is lacking in diagnostic tools (like ping, traceroute, netstat -rn, ifconfig, access to the /etc/resolv.conf equivalant), you may need to borrow another computer (any friends with laptops?) to test.

I know I haven't outlined a step by step, but I hope I provided some additional clues to help resolve the problem.